# Save videos directly to flash drive in IOS 10.3.3

Tags: iphone, video, storage, lightning

So I have a small YouTube channel. Ive been trying lots of different cheap cameras ive had lying around to see which is best. My Dad just got a new iPhone, and I want to start using his old iPhone 5c as my camera. Problem is, it only has less than 3GB of storage with all unnecessary apps deleted and no photos or videos. I need to use an external storage device (Lightning flash drive) to store my videos on. Theres not even enough storage for a single longer shot tho, so I need to store the video directly on the flash drive when recording. Can this be done on IOS 10.3.3? If so how? Thanks!

Edit- Im gonna buy a Lightning flash drive. Is there a professional camera app with manual functions( like ProMovie) that lets you save clips directly to a flash drive?

Comment: SanDisk makes a couple products that should work (iOS 8 and above) [iXPand Flash Dirve](https://amzn.to/30EDylc) or the [SanDisk Wireless Connect Stick](https://amzn.to/3fUuLlC)  I've never used them so I can't tell you how they work or if they are worth the price, so I don't want to answer (at this point).  But give those a shot.

Comment: I looked at the iXpand flash drive and that should work as there is a camera built in to the app that saves directly to the flash drive. Thats exactly what I need, Thanks! Is there one made for videography that has a more advanced camera with manual options?

Comment: I wish I could answer, but I don't have experience with videography on a phone.  On a DSLR, yes, but not a phone.  So, it's not something I keep an eye out for.